# How to test pinch gesture in android simulator

Tags: android, simulator, gesture

I'm trying to add pinch zoom to my app.  The xcode simulators for iphone allow control-click to simulate pinch on an iphone or ipad.  Does the Android simulator have the same capability? If so which API do I need to use for testing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunetly, not at the moment. See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/472b35294374a032?pli=1).

Comment: David Turner posts for the android blog. So, his response proves there is no *official* way.